# documentation to create a like button in a facebook app

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to figure out which facebook documentation is relevant to what I want to do.

I want to create a facebook app which I understand is like a glorified iframe pointing to my web server which will serve just 2 html pages.  On one of my pages, I want to create a link or button that looks like a big orange race car.  When the user clicks on the race car, it fires the "facebook like event", then redirects the user to the second page on my web server.  Right now, I do not know how to create the orange race car like button.

I've already set up the facebook app, and it is correctly reading the web pages on my server.  I am using PHP.

So my question is any of the following:

a) which page of facebook documentation should I read to learn how to do this

b) does anyone know of any example code I can work with?

**In the past, I had to use oauth to have the user register my app and login before they can  do anything with my web app.  But this time, my web app IS A FACEBOOK APP, so I'm hoping i don't have to do any of that oauth process.  This is why i feel lost in the facebook documentation...i'm not sure which parts are specifically relevant to my facebook app's orange car like button, and which is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But this time, my web app IS A FACEBOOK APP, so I'm hoping i don't have to do any of that oauth process.

There you’re wrong already. You will not get any info about the specific user, unless you have them connect to your app first.

> Right now, I do not know how to create the orange race car like button.

Using the normal Like button plugin, you can hardly change anything about its appearance at all. (And you are not allowed to, by Facebook policies.)

So your only viable option to have a button of your own choice that triggers a like, is to use the [Open Graph built-in like action](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/actions/builtin/likes/).

JOHN SAYS - I followed up this question with another -  stackoverflow.com/questions/12607458/like-action-for-facebook which has part of the answer to this question

Comment: The notion "connect to your app".   If a user finds the app through facebook, then adds it.  Does that satisfy that requirement?  In other words, I don't have to use an SDK to create auth tokens and such...

Comment: I have a related question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12607458/like-action-for-facebook

Comment: You will have to use one of the Authentication flows to connect a user to your app, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/ With Authenticated Referrals, Facebook will take care of part(!) of the logic for you, if the user clicks on a link to your app somewhere on Facebook, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals